# flask semaphore-service with tls two-way authentication

Tags: python, nginx, flask, iot, client-certificates

I need to create a simple service that runs on an EC2 machine on Amazon and that coordinates remote devices (raspberry pi) in sharing a particular resource (not important going into details, it is a service that I use very rarely for accessing the remote devices without a public ip and debug & check detailed status).

My idea was to create a local script that runs in each device and that sends a request to the flask app to check if the "remote resource" is allocated to him or not...

- If it is, it starts the respective service
- If it is not, checks if it was using the resource and in case stops the respective service.

This script checks every 5 minute the situation and then waits.

I wanted to use a TLS client certificate based authentication, so that only my devices can access to the flask app.

I am quite blocked on how to move forward. I can't find any module for TLS client authentication (they all require nginx for handling that) and I am not sure if there are already stable tools for doing something similar.

My question is, is there any module for using flask with client authentication directly without a web server (nginx + gunicorn, apache + wsgi) or do I need to set it up? Is there any already stable tool/solution for what I am trying to achieve? I guess this is a very typical problem in IoT applications.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.